# How do I predict the required size of a Base32 Decode output?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a std::string that is base32 encoded and I have a function that decodes it. The function takes a char* input, a char* destination and a length. How do I know what length I will need for the destination? I need to know what array to allocate for the destination. How do I determine the size?

Comment: It might be easier just to use a dynamic container such as `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` instead of pre-allocated buffers, no?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Base32 allows to encode each `5` bits ( as `32 = 2^5` ) using single character.

It means that you need output buffer size for encoding:

```
dst_size = src_size * 8 / 5 (1.6 times larger)
```

But as base32 string length must be multiple of 40 bits:

```
dst_size = (src_size * 8 + 4) / 5
```

Thus, for decoding (base32->binary) required buffer size is accordingly

```
dst_size = ceil( src_size / 1.6 )
```

Comment: Fwiw: you need `(src_size*8 + 4)/5`, accounting for the roundup to the nearest 5-bit boundary. Ex: a single octet requires *two* output chars, one for the low 5 bits, one for the remaining 3 bits of the octet. The inverse for pulling the chars back into octets is similarly adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the encoded base32 string length is computed as follow :

```
ceil(bytesLength / 5.d) * 8
```

`bytesLength / 5.f` because we want to know how many chunks of 5 bytes we have, and ceil because 0.1 chunk is still 1 chunk

`ceil(bytesLength / 5.f) * 8` because a chunk is made of 8 characters.

For the input data `'a'` the encoded result will be `ME======` because we have 1 chunk of 8 characters : two 5bits encoded characters (`ME`) 6 padding characters (`======`)

The same fashion, the decoded length is :

```
bytesLength * 5 / 8
```

But here `bytesLength` is not including the padding characters, thuse for `ME======` `bytelength` is 2, giving `2 * 5 / 8 == 1` we only have 1 byte to decode.

For a visual explanation, see [rfc4648 section 9 (page 11)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)